# Removing all non-alphanumeric characters at end of string

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

How does one remove all non-alphanumeric characters at the end of a string. Eg:

```
Quick @# brown fox -  
Quick @# brown fox##  
Quick @# brown fox  
Quick @# brown fox @$#
```

all become

```
Quick @# brown fox
```

Seeking to possibly use `preg_replace` because `ereg_replace` is deprecated.

It could also be tweaked to allow specific non-alphanumeric characters at end of string, eg quotes, exclamation marks, question marks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$str = 'Quick @# brown fox @$#';
$rep = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+\Z/i', '', $str);
var_dump($rep);
```

Comment: any way to allow reassigning on var_dump, eg: $a = var_dump($rep)?

Comment: what var_dump() does is print the variable content and type, is used to debug/view the variable content, so you don't need that line only to test things out, $rep is holding you're changed string you can do whatever you like with it .

Comment: so you whant to allow a-z ( the alfabet ), 0-9 ( numbers ) AND single/double quotes, question mark too ? then you couls use `'/[^a-z0-9\'"\?!\`;]+\Z/i'`

Answer (score 1):

```
$rep = preg_replace('/\W+$/', '', $str);
```

Comment: +1 I was thinking about something like this. One thing: \W will not match an underscore, so you might want to look for that explicitly.

Comment: $ entails a newline only, \Z entails a newline or end of subject and is more appropriate for my case, cheers.